# Increment allow users in authorization in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, forms-authentication

I use forms authentication for users of my site. and some of users can enter some pages based on web.config:

```
  <authorization>
     <allow users="admin"/>
    </authorization>
```

I want to increment allow users dynamically .(users table is in database) .Can I do this?

Comment: This question is really unclear. Do you mean *implement* the authorization dynamically?

Comment: yes , I want increment users without adding tags in web.config .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a roles provider and set the web.config to allow or deny based on the roles.

In your web.config

```
<authorization>
   <allow roles="Administrators" />
   <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

In your page code, use the [`Roles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) class.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you  give me an example?